# Java Error illegal start of expression cause .withPermission

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to do run program but it throws me an error "error: illegal start of expression" and the method we use to is red highlighted on editor that's `.withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)`

The main problem in `.withPermission`,doesn't work

```
 public void runtime() {
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
```

Comment: What did you expect that code to do? What is `withPermission`? Is that from [Dexter](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter)? If so, see examples of how to use on their web site by click the [link](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter#usage).

Answer (score 0):

You started the statement but never ended it.
Close the statement with '}'.

```
       public void runtime() {
            .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)}
```